# Vim Function to Send Highlighted Text to a Git Commit

Tags: git, vim, viml

#### Problem:

Suppose I have the following text in my vim buffer:

```
This is a commit msg.
```

Suppose further I have a git repo located at `~/my_repo`.

**Goal:** Make a vim script so that I can highlight the text above, and have it sent as a git commit message within `~/my_repo`. It would look something like

```
:'<,'>Commit ~/my_repo
```

It would also have auto-complete on its repo argument.

#### Attempted Solution:

First, the autocomplete function (AFAIK I think this is OK?):

```
function! GitLocations()
  return find $HOME -name '.git' -printf '%h\n' "generates a list of all folders which contain a .git dir
endfunction
```

Next, the actual git commit function, which is incomplete:

```
function! CommitTextGitRepo(l1, l2, loc)
  let s:msg = ??? " how do I make this the highlighted text from line l1 to line l2?
  execute '!cd ' . a:loc . '&& git commit --allow-empty -m \"' . s:msg '\"'
endfunction
```

Assuming I can figure out how to get `CommitTextGitRepo()` working above, the final thing I would need is this (I think):

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=custom,GitLocations -range Commit call CommitToGitRepo(<line1>, <line2>, <q-args>)
```

I'm so close. How do I finish this up? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
join(getline(a:l1, a:l2),"\n")
```

should do the trick 
I would rather use a local variable and you might want to shellescape the message making the function close to this

```
function! CommitTextGitRepo(l1, l2, loc)
  let l:msg = join(getline(a:l1,a:l2), "\n")
  execute '!cd ' . a:loc . '&& git commit --allow-empty -m ' . shellescape(l:msg)
endfunction
```

http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29